# Nodejs Worker threads - How many workers should I spawn in the pool?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node-worker-threads

I want to use Nodejs [Worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) to handle cpu intensive tasks. I will create a pool of workers available for this.

My question is: **How many workers should I spawn in the pool?**

Assuming I have a 4 cores, 8 threads cpu - should I spawn a max of 3 or 7 workers (based on cores or threads)? I assume that I have to keep 1 core/thread free for the main process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a few tests with [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool). Based on these, my conclusion is that the worker pool just contain a maximum of n - 1 workers, n being the number of threads a cpu has.

For instance, if I have a 10 core, 20 threads CPU, I should spawn at most 19 workers in my pool.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but mostly suggested number is dependent on a number of CPUs.

for example, node uses 4 worker threads.

in [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool) The default number of maxWorkers is the number of CPUs minus one. When the number of CPUs could not be determined maxWorkers is set to 3.